# Is there another name for this puzzle? (Kyudoku, Nine Find)

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, puzzle-identification

Is there another name for this type of puzzle? I can only find two examples of it online:

- https://www.brainzilla.com/logic/kyudoku/
- http://ninefind.com/

In the game you start with a 6x6 grid filled with the numbers 1 to 9. One number on the grid is circled. The aim is to remove numbers (you can't remove the circled number) so that:

- The sum in every row and column is 9 or less
- Each number (1 to 9) appears only once

For example, you might start with this grid:

[image: initial grid]

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | 5 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | ⑤ | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | 5 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 6 |

And remove all of the number 5's except for the one that is circled:

[image: grid after removing other 5s]

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2 | - | 1 | - | 8 |
| 9 | 9 | 7 | 9 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 6 | 8 | - | - | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | ⑤ | - | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 8 | 2 |
| 3 | - | 9 | 7 | - | 6 |

You can then remove the numbers 7, 8 and 9 from column 3 because, when added to 5, the answer is greater than 9. And so on, until you end up with a grid that looks like:

[image: final grid]

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| - | 2 | - | 1 | - | - |
| 9 | - | - | - | - | - |
| - | 6 | - | - | - | 3 |
| - | - | ⑤ | - | - | 4 |
| - | - | - | - | 8 | - |
| - | - | - | 7 | - | - |

Comment: FWIW, googling "九独" (*kyudoku* in Japanese) doesn't return any puzzles...

Answer (score -1):

I believe not. We did just learn about it existing a few days ago. Plus, googling the word Kyudoku gives [this link](https://www.geniol.com.br/logica/kyudoku/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1_6VPd3W_s), so I believe that Kyudoku is the only existing name.

Comment: However, not having any hits for _this particular name_ doesn't mean the puzzle type doesn't have a different name. And maybe _you_ just learned about it a few days ago, but it has been around for longer than that.