# Kyudoku :- Merry Christmas?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

Previous Puzzle:- [Kyudoku :- Introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105989/kyudoku-introduction)

There will be numbers in a grid. You just have to circle nine unique numbers (1 to 9) such that each row and column has sum of 9 or less. In some puzzles, one or more circled numbers may already be given.

Here is today's puzzle.

Note that this puzzle will be unsolvable. However, if you interchange 2 digits by their positions, the puzzle can uniquely be solved. Can you find how to solve this puzzle?

**Note**:- There is some brainwork you might have to do. You have to interchange 2 digits, such that the solution becomes unique. There may be a case when you interchange 2 digits and you found solutions, but the solution is not unique in that case.

[image]

|  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | ① | 4 | 1 | 5 | 9 |
| 2 | 6 | 5 | 3 | 5 | 8 |
| 9 | 7 | 9 | 3 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 6 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 | 8 | 3 | 2 | 7 |
| 9 | 5 | X | 2 | 8 | 8 |

**Bonus**:- There is an Easter Egg hidden in the puzzle. Can you find it? (Check the Title first) .
**Bonus**:- There is a shaded box in the figure. Can you guess what number it can take?

**Edit**: @Smartest1here has provided a solution which contradicts mine, but his/her solution perfectly works. That, of course, does not make the puzzle unique, but I want a direct logical path from him/her to get to the solution. My solution, has a direct logical path. Also what I have in mind is 2 solutions, which also, is a problem =) .

**Edit**: I thought this puzzle would be interesting, so right now I am not concerned with uniqueness, as there are 3 solutions I found for now, 1 found by @Smartest1here. There are 2 more solutions I have in mind, the puzzle is still open for now.

Comment: Can the shaded box be interchanged too?

Comment: No, except the shaded box, you have to interchange 2 digits by their positions.

Comment: Is the number in the shaded box significant to the solution, if so, it should not be a bonus.

Comment: No it is not, that it why it is given a bonus. Just consider it to be a barrier, it is of no use to the solution to the puzzle.

Comment: I don't really know anything about this type of puzzle. Can someone explain to me why it's downvoted? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but I believe the downvotes are because this is a [grid-deduction] puzzle with multiple possible solutions - setters are expected to check their grid-deductions for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution:

> [image]

Proof: for a moment let us assume the 3 and 5 is swapped:

> If we then assume that C1R3 is circled we will get a contradiction in column 3: [image]

> Then if we assume that C3R3 is circled we get a contradiction in that all 5s are eliminated: [image]

Then

> C1R6 must be circled leading us to: [image]

Then a hypothetical leads us to a contradiction:

> That there are no sixes that can be circled: [image]

So:

> C6R2 must be circled leading us to: [image]

Then:

> 5,3 and 4 must be circled leading us to: [image] and then finally: [image].

How I got the numbers to interchange:

> I started of with these basic deductions:[image]

Then:

> I basically repeated the same procedure as the steps above in the proof and I found the same contradictions until I reached: [image]

Lastly:

> I saw that either 5 or 4 needed to be swapped with either a 2 or a 3 and with some experimentation I found the swap which lead me to a single solution so it seemed. Then I tried it with the proof procedure above to see whether it allowed for any new solutions with the former contradictions I had acheived which would disprove it but it did not affect the contradictions hence this must be the swap.

Comment: Nevermind I will provide the explanations anyway.

Comment: Not what I had in mind, but this perfectly works. The fact is, I was thinking in a different way, and you thought differently. Can you explain how you got that? because what I found as my answer was from direct logical deduction. First of all, what made you think you should interchange $3$ and $5$ only?

Comment: Don't wait for confirmation to provide explanations; you should be confident in your logical path to solve [grid-deduction] and post with that path presented.

Comment: Ok I analysed your approach, it is absolutely correct. But here's more to tell, there are more solutions. I understood why it's not pure logical deduction as approaching this differently can give you different solutions, especially you are allowed to interchange any digits.

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer to the grid but the bonus question:

The answer is:

> 0 as the number of the shaded grid as the numbers represent decimals of $\pi$

Also:

> Is it related to the title?